# at server i keep getting socketio request constantly every 2 seconds, but google analytics show no one is here.

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I've removed all socketio code but someone either hasn't uploaded page for days or something else. But for some reason server is getting bombarded with socketio request which are failing because i removed all the code both on client and server. However, they are still coming. ??? what can i do. Block ip?

I can't change webdomain name. Which is given. I can't think of any options, they're coming from like 6 different ips. They would have been legit requests some weeks ago. but not now.

Answer (score 2):

Are you worried that handling these requests will impede your server's performance? The only legitimate reason I can think of is that someone's browser cache hasn't been cleared properly since the update, assuming you enabled caching on your express server.

If your intention is to improve performance, I suggest putting that path high on the express method chain so that the server can end the request as quickly as possible and minimize the load on the server.

If you want the people to become aware that their requests are invalid, you could route the path to a javascript file that redirects the current page to another document. On the document, have directions that instruct the user to clear their browser cache in order to properly update their client.

Hope that helps.